# what view to use to create home top view map dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, flutter, android-view

I am creating an android app which has to show a map of home so which view in android to use to create it here is some sample example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nThW.png

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter you can use an [AssetImage](https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/) and wrap it into a `Container`

```
new Container(
    child: AssetImage('graphics/background.png'),
),
```

to fill the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Stack**. With the help stack, you can create an overlay widget Application. You can check the detail of Stack [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/06/flutter-design-user-interface-with.html).